# x86 Assembly Creating Strings and Arrays on Stack

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm a little confused on how to create strings and and empty array on a stack using x86 assembly.

To create a string I have ...

```
PUSH .ascii "myString"
```

I am confused on how to create an empty array. I understand to create an array with an element of 0 it looks like....

```
PUSH 0
```

Not sure how to create an empty array and I'm not sure if this is the correct way to create a string on the stack.

Comment: What use is an empty array?

Comment: I'm actually trying to convert my javascript code into x86 assembly so the reason could be we want an empty array initially and when the user inputs something we can insert it into the array

Comment: Oh, you want a dynamic array. And on the stack? Good luck.

Comment: Well it doesn't have to be dynamic, I'm just giving an example of what I can do with that empty array. I'm more concerned about putting an empty array on the stack

Comment: If it's not dynamic, then you don't have to do anything. There's nothing you can do with an empty static array anyway.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. To make sure I'm understanding this correctly, if I'm calling a function (say execve the sys call) i can just deference the stack pointer (considering there's nothing on the stack) and pass that value into execve? Or would I have to push 0x0 (NULL) onto the stack first?

Comment: `mov esp, 0` is a recipe for disaster in virtually all scenarios I can think of.

Comment: You're right I changed my solution but is that the same as having an empty array?

Comment: Also, you should specify in your question the exact task you are trying to accomplish, possibly in C or in something similar. Assembly is... quite low level, and many high level concepts you may have in mind from JavaScript may not have a straight mapping to assembly, so to have meaningful answers it would be helpful to understand the exact context.

Comment: `execve` arguments cannot be empty arrays (whatever that means - there's no such a thing as an empty array in C or assembly, either you have a first element to point to or you have no array), they are all arrays of some unspecified dimension terminated by a last NULL element. If you want to build such an array on the stack, push your stuff in reverse order (so, NULL first - remember, the stack grows towards lower addresses), and pass the address of the first element (=the last you pushed, AKA esp after the last push) as argument (where it must be placed depends from the calling convention).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split it into 3 problems - allocating (uninitialised) space on the stack, freeing that space after, and initialising/using the space while its allocated.

To create (uninitialised) space on the stack you only need to subtract the amount of bytes needed from the stack pointer. For example, to allocate space for an array of 20 (4-byte) integers you can do `sub esp,20*4`.

To free space on the stack you do the reverse of what you did to allocate it. For example, to free the space for an array of 20 (4-byte) integers you can do `add esp,20*4`.

To initialise or use the space, you just need something to determine the address. This can be `esp`.

For example, to allocate an array of 20 (4-byte) integers, set the 10th integer in the array to 0x1234567 and then free the array you could do:

```
    sub esp,20*4
    mov dword [esp+9*4],0x1234567
    add esp,20*4
```

You can combine multiple allocations together. For example:

```
    sub esp,124 + 20*4                  ;Allocate space for a 20 integer array and a 124 character string
    mov dword [esp+9*4 + 124],0x1234567 ;Set 10th element (being careful to skip over the space for the string)
    add esp,124                         ;Free space for the string
    mov dword [esp+9*4],0x89ABCDEF      ;Set 10th element again
    add esp,20*4                        ;Free space for the array
```

You can also combine allocation with initialisation. For example:

```
    push dword 3     ;Allocate "array[3]" and set it to 3
    push dword 2     ;Allocate "array[2]" and set it to 2
    push dword 1     ;Allocate "array[1]" and set it to 1
    push dword 0     ;Allocate "array[0]" and set it to 0
    mov [esp+1*4],5  ;Change "array[1]" to 5
    add esp,4*4      ;Free the array
```

And you can mix both. For example:

```
    push dword 3     ;Allocate "array[3]" and set it to 3
    push dword 2     ;Allocate "array[2]" and set it to 2
    sub esp,2*4      ;Allocate "array[0]" and "array[1]" without initialising them
    mov [esp+1*4],5  ;Change "array[1]" to 5
    add esp,4*4      ;Free the array
```

However, "initialisation during allocation" gets a little trickier when the sizes don't match the default size of things on the stack. For example, if it was an array of 16-bit integers, you might do:

```
    push dword (3 << 16) | 2  ;Allocate "array[3]" and "array[2]" and set them
    sub esp,2*2               ;Allocate "array[0]" and "array[1]" without initialising them
    mov [esp+1*2],5           ;Change "array[1]" to 5
    add esp,4*2               ;Free the array
```

Strings are just arrays (arrays of characters). For example:

```
    push dword 'n' | ('g' << 8) | ('.' << 16) | (0 << 24)   ;Allocate space for last 4 chars and set them to "ng.\0"
    push dword 'S' | ('t' << 8) | ('r' << 16) | ('i' << 24) ;Allocate space for middle 4 chars and set them to "Stri"
    push dword 'T' | ('h' << 8) | ('e' << 16) | (' ' << 24) ;Allocate space for first 4 chars and set them to "The "
    mov byte [esp+14],'!'                                   ;Change the string from "The String.\0" to "The String!\0"
    add esp,16*1                                            ;Free the string
```

Note that most assemblers provide a shorthand for combining characters into a larger (e.g. 32-bit) number that makes things a little easier. For example:

```
    push dword "ng."      ;Allocate space for last 4 chars and set them to "ng.\0"
    push dword "Stri"     ;Allocate space for middle 4 chars and set them to "Stri"
    push dword "The "     ;Allocate space for first 4 chars and set them to "The "
    mov byte [esp+14],'!' ;Change the string from "The String.\0" to "The String!\0"
    add esp,16*1          ;Free the string
```

Note that you can not do `push dword "The String."`. In this case the assembler would convert the bytes into a huge 88 bit integer (using the same `value = (char0 << 0) | (char1 << 8) | (char2 << 8*2) | (char3 << 8*3) ...  | (charN << 8*N)` logic) and the resulting 88 bit integer won't fit in 32-bits that the `push` instruction puts on the stack.

You can initialise the string on the stack from data elsewhere. For example:

```
    section .rodata
defaultString:  db "The String.", 0
.end:
    section .text

    sub esp,16*1                              ;Allocate space for 16 characters
    mov edi,esp                               ;edi = address of the destination string
    mov esi,defaultString                     ;esi = address of the source string
    mov ecx,defaultString.end - defaultString ;ecx = size of the string
    cld
    rep movsb                                 ;Initialise the string (by copying it from defaultString)

    mov byte [esp+14],'!'                     ;Change the string from "The String.\0" to "The String!\0"
    add esp,16*1                              ;Free the string
```

This "initialisation by copying from read-only data" technique works for arrays (and strings) of any size.

Comment: I'm just missing in this question mention of the `ebp` being often used to copy initial `esp` for easier-to-follow-by-human way of working with local stack memory inside particular function, as addressing directly through `esp` requires the programmer to dynamically recalculate the offsets by current state of stack, while the "frame pointer" in `ebp` doesn't need that, offsets may be fixed per function.

Comment: @Ped7g: For 32-bit 80x86 there are only 7 registers that you can really use (which often isn't enough to avoid temporary loads/stores). Wasting an entire register and using it as "frame pointer" just because of ancient poorly designed symbolic debuggers (intended for a completely unrelated language) should be considered a criminal offence, and has nothing to do with the question asked.